# MySQL Partitioning, Reorganize Max Value partition (Known Bug / Feature)

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have written a crone job which reorganizes last max value partition every week into 2 new partitions , one for the previous week , and one for the future data (new max value partition **which initially is empty**).

I have noticed that the previous max value partition is copied to a 2 new files (one for the previous week partition and one for the new max value partition), the second file is empty since it represents a partition for future not existing data.

Then i wondered why recopying data from previous max value partition to new partition file and then deleting the previous max value file, and creating a new empty max value partition file, it seems as a big waste of time.

I have to mention i deal with MyISAM tables, Additionally i have stumbled on this reported [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65286) which describes very similar conditions.

1. Is there a workaround method to achieve the behavior i have suggested (renaming the partition of max value to a new partition name and replacing the max value constrain by a new current max value measurement, then creating a new max value empty partition?
2. Can you suggest other way to close a partition -> activate some command that will close (add max limitation on the previous max value partition) an open a new max value partition?